# Why doesn't the subscription of the relay work even though there is a value passed to it?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have set up a `relay` like this:

```
class CustomAlertViewController: UIViewController {
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    var alertTextRelay = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")

    alertTextField.rx.value.orEmpty.changed.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] value in
         print("THIS IS RIGHT", value)
          self?.alertTextRelay.accept(value)
          print("THIS IS ALSO RIGHT", self?.alertTextRelay.value)  
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
...
```

I get the text writen in the `textField` and accept it to the `relay` and check so that the value is really there. But the subscription never trigger:

```
class RecievingClass: UIViewController {
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    let instance = CustomAlertViewController()

    instance.alertTextRelay.subscribe(onNext: { value in
        self.myText = value
            
     }, onError: { error in
         print(error)
     }, onCompleted: {
         print("completed")
     }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

...
```

Nothing in the `subscription` is triggered. Why? If it helps, `CustomAlertViewController` is used as a custom `alert` (a `view` on an overlay). Also, there are a lot of `static` functions in `CustomAlertViewController`. Not sure if that's relevant. Let me know if I can provide anything else.

Comment: The problem has to do with where you put the code in the classes. You haven't given us enough information. Post code that compiles and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this alertTextField.rx.value.orEmpty.changed.subscribe on this alertTextField.rx.text.orEmpty.asObservable(). And add [weak self] for RecievingClass in other way you get memory leak.